# jquery .txt() add multiple values?

Tags: jquery, ajax

My script returns multiple values that I want to show in a span but I cannot find anything in the jquery docs how to do this. A single var is fine, .`text(reponse.messsage)` works but I need to combine multiple values.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'script.php',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        if (response.script == "run") {
            $('list').text(response.message response.progress response.name Some Plain Text);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: are you saying that "script.php" return a json with various data and you need to take this data with ajax?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Strings#Concatenating_strings

Comment: @J03Bukowski correct, it returns an array with values.

Comment: the variable "response" give you the whole json array. For example if you had this array "{key: value}", use the "key" after the "response" to take the value (response.key). Can you also put the code in "script.php"?

Comment: Add your `console.log(response )` in the question

Comment: `$('list').text(response.message +  response.progress + response.name + " Some Plain Text")` ?

Comment: *"an array with values"* - `response.message` indicates it's *not* an "array" - please include at least a small sample of the json/object `response`

Comment: @AbbasEbadian Thank you, that was what I was looking for. Could you please mark your reply as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should concatenate your strings using "+" operator :

```
$('list').text(response.message +  response.progress + response.name + " Some Plain Text");
```